# Posso usar minha conta do Stack Overflow internacional no Stack Overflow em português?

Tags: suporte

Gostaria de usar a mesma conta nos dois Stack Overflows; seria isto possível?

Answer (score 7):

Não, cada site tem uma conta diferente.

Na verdade, as duas contas são ligadas à conta da rede Stack Exchange, então elas são basicamente a mesma, porém, cada site tem suas conquistas separadas: reputação, medalhas, privilégios.

Answer (score 5):

Creio que você está vendo sob a perspectiva errada. Vamos então tentar ter uma visão correta?

O que acontece é que a rede Stack Exchange é um grafo bipartido com dois tipos de vértices:

- usuário SE
- sítio SE

Um usuário SE pode se relacionar com diversos sítios SE, assim como um sítio SE tem diversos usuários. Mas um sítio não tem outro sítio (portanto um subgrafo apenas dos sítios SE é um conjunto de vértices sem aresta alguma), e o mesmo com um usuário. Como os subgrafos `sítios` e `usuários` não possuem arestas mas o grafo `sítios-usuários` possue, então dizemos que o grafo `sítios-usuários` é bipartido.

#### Como se dá essa bipartição?

Bem, já falei o que significam os vértices, mas não falei das arestas. Cada aresta, por si, representa que o usuário pertence ao sítio. A aresta é colorida (ou seja, possui propriedades por si mesma), e sua cor é a conta do usuário no sítio específico. Também creio que não seja possível ter duas arestas no mesmo par `(usuário,sítio)`

> (excetuando possivelmente algum caso de usuário cancelou a ligação uma vez e, posteriormente, criou outro vínculo)

Answer (score 4):

NÃO, são sites diferentes, todas contas são vinculadas de alguma forma (através do site stackexchange.com) mas são exclusivas para os sites respectivos.

O score também é isolado e não tem motivo para para compartilhar o score, o score é um simbolo do que você fez pela comunidade especifica, não tem motivo para mover para outra.

Answer (score 4):

Como os outras respostas já comentaram, não, porém quando vc ganha 200 pontos em (acho que) qualquer um dos sites, vc ganha um "bonus de associacão" de 100 pontos em todas as contas. Isso lhe permite votar, colocar figuras e fazer as coisas mais básicas. De resto vc tem que merecer!